# Unable to give a default value to a filtered table

Tags: c#

I've just signed up today. I've been writing and maintaining my company's Delphi ERP program for years. Last year my boss wanted me to rewrite the whole ERP using C#. It took my many month to learn and build my basic C# code. Everything went well. Delphi skills help  C# coding. Anyway it's still Windows program. But when it came to master-detail structure, I got stuck in a swamp.

It's a piece of cake using Delphi to write a master-detail program. The only thing I need is filter. Unlike C#, A Delphi DataGrid always has the same number of rows as the corresponding table does. Because I used filters to achieve master-detail in Delphi, I did the same (I didn't use ralation) with C#, and the result was a mess.

What's wrong with the way I implement master-detail ? Do I have to use relation ? I am willing to use relation because sometimes I want to access all the rows in a table. Or else, could any one give me a good example of master-detail ?

To save your time, I just outline things.

master :  DataGridView1 <- BindingSource1 <- Table1

detail :　DataGridView2 <- BindingSource2 <- Table2

KeyColumn : RelateNo

filter inside dataGridView1_SelectionChanged():

```
bindingSource2.Filter = string.Format("RelateNo = '{0}'", ds.Tables["Table1"].Rows[bindingSource1.Position]["RelateNo"].ToString());
```

default values neccessary for filter :

```
ds.Tables["Table1"].RowChanging -= new DataRowChangeEventHandler(DetailRow_Changing); 
ds.Tables["Table2"].RowChanging += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(DetailRow_Changing); 

private void DetailRow_Changing(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{ 
  if (e.Action == DataRowAction.Add) 
  {             
e.Row.Table.Columns["RelateNo"].DefaultValue = ds.Tables["Table1"].Rows[bindingSource1.Position]["RelateNo"].ToString();
  }
}
```

I think the above is not complicated at all. These are the problems I'm facing :

1. I press the [new] button. A row in the master is automatically added. I typed something. I click the top left cell in DataGridView2. I typed something. I hit TAB a few time or hit the down arrow key to add a new row. The first row I just finished typing dissappered. Only one empty row is left on DataGridView2. I traced it and found out DetailRow_Changing() did execute correctly, meaning that a row was added. Beacuse Table1's RelateNo didn't get to copy to Table2, making the newly added row slip away from the filter.
2. Similar to above. I click the top left cell in DataGridView2. I press F2 (code in KeyDown) to bring up a dialog from which I can choose a ProductId. After the dialog closed, I checked if a new DataRow is needed. If so, I execute :
   DataGridView2.EndEdit();
   CurrencyManager cm = (CurrencyManager)grid.BindingContext[DataGridView2.DataSource, DataGridView2.DataMember];
     cm.EndCurrentEdit(); // add one DataRow

I verify that a DataRow is added by :

labelHint.Text =  ds.Tables["Table2"].Rows.Count.ToString();

I try to get the DataView

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)acDataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView2.CurrentCell.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
if (drv == null)
  MessageBox.Show("null");   // This line was executed
else
{
int i = ds.Tables["Detail"].Rows.IndexOf(drv.Row); 
ds.Tables["Detail"].Rows[i]["ProductId"] = WhatEverDialogBox.GetValue("ProductId");      
bindingSource3.ResetBindings(false);
}
```

Again, RelateNo didn't get the correct value. Everything is about default values. I found out that if a DataTable is not filtered, it can get default values correctly. What is up with filtered DataTabled ?

Comment: What UI Framework are you using? WPF or Windows Forms?

Answer (score 0):

I put it inside bindingSource_PosionChanged(). This is a better place to give default values. But how about ModifiedTime ? It could be one hour ago.